# MATLAB Error: Input image may not contain NaNs

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am making a traffic sign detection and recognition program in MATLAB for my semester project. By now I have been successful in doing every step correct.

Image >> Normalized Image >> Scaling & Intensifying Image >> Thresholding >> Morphological Operations

I have normalized the image by using this formula:
`NORM_COLOR = COLOR/sqrt(RED^2 + GREEN^2 + BLUE^2);`

I have scaled my image by the factor of sqrt(3) and intensified by element-wise multiplication to the normalized image.

In thresholing, I have zeroed all three channels (RGB) where this condition is true:

> RED < 0.34 OR GREEN > 0.2621

This all gives me an image where all colors (excluding red) are blacked. This is the image I get: 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D81jc.png)

Now, when I do morphological operations like `imerode` it gives me this error:

> Error using morphmex
> Input image may not contain NaNs.
>
> Error in morphop (line 69)
>       B = morphmex(mex_method, B, double(getnhood(se(k))), getheight(se(k)), unpacked_M);
>
> Error in imerode (line 123)
>  B =
>   morphop(A,se,'erode',mfilename,varargin{:});
>
> Error in anas (line 64)
>  img_seg = imerode(img,se);

This is the code I have written for erosion:

```
se = strel('disk', 2);
img_seg = imerode(img,se);
imshow(img_seg);
```

Any one could help me with this problem? Thankyou :)

Comment: Oh yes! Thankyou! It really helped me. I actually didn't know what NaNs mean, so I was blanked what to do next. Thankyou so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try avoiding division by zero:

```
NORM_COLOR = COLOR/sqrt(RED^2 + GREEN^2 + BLUE^2+0.0000001);
```